# postgresql 9.4 + BDR Fails

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, postgresql-bdr

I'm trying to get postgresql 9.4 and BDR working. Following this tutorial: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_Quick_Start

Actually, my sysadmin provided me with a package to test with. He's taken care of the compilation "stuff".

I have two instances running, one on port 5598 and the other on 5599. What I'm noticing is that when I leave the following line in the postgresql.conf file, I can't start the service:

```
 # Load BDR
 shared_preload_libraries = 'bdr'
```

the error message i get is:

> FATAL:  could not access file "bdr": No such file or directory

When I remove the above line, it I can start the service on the specific port needed.
According to the BDR docs, if you get that message, you're missing the bdr contrib package:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_Reference#Could_not_access_file_.22bdr.22:_No_such_file_or_directory

But I have it installed. I just don't know how to verify it because I don't exactly know what it does.

When i check my package manager to see everything that's been installed, I have the following items listed:

```
postgresql-bdr
postgresql-bdr-contrib
postgresql-bdr-dbg
```

My apologies in advance for being such a noob. But i'm not a sysadmin, linux is relatively new to me... and it looks like BDR is pretty new too. I'm just trying to collect as much information as possible for my sysadmins to be able to fix whatever is wrong with this package...

Thanks.

Comment: I was getting the same error.Try this method .It works. http://evol-monkey.blogspot.com/2014/08/postgresql-bi-directional-replication.html

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial on that link is not complete. 
You should type

```
apt-get install bdr-9.4
```

instead of

```
apt-get install postgresql-bdr-9.4
```

After that everything is working fine..

I also lose some time to figure that out..

Comment: I tested and works! Thanks... The reason is when querying using regex 'bdr-9.4'is able to get all the packages needed.